# Questions on a proof of Sylow's $1°$

Tags: abstract-algebra, proof-explanation

The statement of Sylow's $1°$ theorem in this case is the following: let $G$ be a finite group and $p$ be a prime number such that $|G|=p^{k}m$ where $p$ does not divide $m$; then, there exists a $p$-Sylow's subgroup of $G$ (that is, there exists a subgroup of $G$ of order $p^k$). The proof I read goes like that. Let $X$ be the family of subsets of $G$ of $p^k$ elements. We define the action $*:G×X\rightarrow X$ as $(g,U)\mapsto gU$. Now, $\binom {p^{k}m} {p^k}$ is the number of elements of $X$ and, by a previous lemma, we know that $p$ does not divide $|X|$. So it has to be a $V\in X$ such that $p$ does not divide $|O(V)|$, where $O(V)$ is the orbit of $V$. But, by a known formula, $|G|=|St_{V}||O(V)|$ so, given that $p^k||G|$, $p^k||St_{V}|$. Now, by definition of $St_{V}$ and $*$, given an element $v\in V$ and given an element $g\in St_{V}<G$, $gv\in V\rightarrow St_{V}v\subseteq V\forall v\in V$ $\rightarrow |St_{V}v|\le |V|=p^k$. As we know $|St_{V}v|=|St_{V}|$, $St_{V}$ is a subgroup of $G$ of exactly $p^k$ elements. The confusing parts for me are why it has to be a $V\in X$ such that $p$ does not divide $|O(V)|$ and how we concluded from $|St_{V}v|=|St_{V}|$ that $|St_{V}|=p^{k}$.

Comment: If all the orbits were of size divisible by $p$ then, since orbits are disjoint, their union, the whole set $X$, would have size divisible by $p$.

Comment: I knew orbits partition the set $X$, but I did not think about this. Thanks.